# How to determine/test FaceTime contact information?

Tags: ios, ios7, facetime

I am making a FaceTime enabled iOS app.  I'm using FaceTime url schemes to launch FaceTime which works great.  I want users to be able to select contacts from their address book, store off their FaceTime contact info, and use that later.

A contact could have several pieces of contact information (phone number, several email addresses, etc).  How can I determine which is the one FaceTime needs?  My understanding is that in iOS 7, when a user chooses to FaceTime a contact from their contact list, it will try ringing all of their phone numbers/email address simultaneously.  Is there a way to do that from my app?  Alternatively, is there a way for my app to test if a piece of contact information is a valid FaceTime contact?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question? I'd like to know if a user has FaceTime enabled in the address book. Thanks